# Get value with the clause IF and IN

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are data in a date column like:

> '2014-03-01', '2014-05-01', '2014-07-01' ...

I want to get distinct years with the IF clause.

For example, if the date is in 'YEAR-07-01' ~ '(YEAR+1)-06-30', then it returns YEAR, else it returns YEAR-1.

For Example, if the data of the date column is like:

> '2000-06-01', '2000-07-01', '2005-07-01',  '2005-08-01', '2008-07-01'

I want to get '1999', '2000', '2005', '2008'

I am thinking

```
SELECT (
IF t.DATE IN YEAR(t.DATE) + '-07-01' AND YEAR(t.DATE)+1 + '-06-30'
THEN YEAR(t.DATE) ELSE YEAR(t.DATE)+1 )
FROM THE_TABLE t WHERE PRIMARY_KEY = 123;
```

But I don't know how to write it correctly in SQL Server.

Comment: Use the words `CASE WHEN` instead of `IF`.  You might also need to write `CAST(YEAR(t.DATE) AS VARCHAR(4))` to get the concatenation to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me you're doing a calculation based on a fiscal year ending 6/30 and starting 7/1.

Try this:

```
select distinct
case when Month(t.DATE) >=7 then Year(t.DATE) else Year(t.DATE)-1 end as FiscalYear
from THE_TABLE t
order by FiscalYear desc
```

Comment: It works like a charm.  How can I add DISTINCT? and I want to order by YEAR(t.DATE) DESC.

Comment: Oh I added SELECT DISTINCT(CASE WHEN ...), and it works, but I don't know where should I put the clause 'ORDER BY'

Comment: I edited the query to show where the order by clause would go.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  But I want to use DISTINCT and ORDER BY both.  It gives error..

Comment: I updated the SQL again.  If you use distinct in the select list, you then use the derived name in the order by clause.   I changed it to order by FiscalYear desc (the derived column name)

Answer (score 0):

Even better would be to create and use a calendar table. Not only is it easier to work with it can then be flexible across different years.

Take a look at this article. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/70482/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(YEAR(t.DATE) + '-07-01' AS DATE) AND CAST((YEAR(t.DATE)+1) + '-06-30' AS DATE)
            THEN YEAR(t.DATE)
       ELSE YEAR(t.DATE)+1
       END AS YearValue
FROM   THE_TABLE t
WHERE  PRIMARY_KEY = 123
```